# Selecting with dplyr by variable name, some column names are numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to select column names by passing a vector argument to dplyr's select:

```
df <- data.frame("A" = letters[1:5], "B" = letters[6:10], "2015" = rep(1, 5), check.names = F)
vars <- c("A", "2015")
select_(df, .dots = vars)
Error: Position must be between 0 and n
```

I think it interprets column `2015` as a number and fails because there are only three columns in `df`. Is there a way of select both columns without renaming column `2015` to something like `X2015`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found out I can just use `one_of`:

```
select(df, one_of(vars))
A 2015
a    1
b    1
c    1
d    1
e    1
```

But probably @akrun is right that I should avoid numeric column names.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use regular expressions:

```
dplyr::select(df, matches("A|2015"))
```

Btw: the `select_` method takes indices as input, i.e., you could as well use `vars  <- grep("A|2015", colnames(df))`